# How can I order a table with decimal numbers and letters

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Hello I'm facing a problem.

I want to order my table by decimal and after by letter.

For exemple I got this :

```
5.3 Choice 3
A-Choice 4
1.2 Choice 1
1.5 Choice 2
C-Choice 5
```

And I want it to be that way :

```
1.2 Choice 1
1.5 Choice 2
5.3 Choice 3
A-Choice 4
C-Choice 5
```

I tried something like that

```
const compare = (a, b) => {
        if (!isNaN(b.label.charAt(0)))
        {
            if (a.label === b.label) {
                return 0
             };
             const aArr = a.label.split("."), bArr = b.label.split(".");
             for (let i = 0; i < Math.min(aArr.length, bArr.length); i++) {
                if (parseInt(aArr[i]) < parseInt(bArr[i])) {
                   return -1
                };
                if (parseInt(aArr[i]) > parseInt(bArr[i])) {
                   return 1
                };
             }
             if (aArr.length < bArr.length) {
                return -1
             };
             if (aArr.length > bArr.length) {
                return 1
             };
             return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            return a.label > b.label;
        }
        
     };
     processus.sort(compare);
```

But it's not working..
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try the sort using string comparison (i.c. [`localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)).

`localeCompare` is not sufficient if the values after 'Choice' may be > 9 (e.g. `'1.2 Choice 23'`. In that case you'll need to to sort twice, something like the snippet.

```js
const toSort = getToSort();

log(`\n**Choice always [< 10], localeCompare sufficient`,
  toSort.simple
  .sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b))
  .join(`\n`)
);

// this does not work for a choice values > 9
log(`\n**Choice may be [> 9], localeCompare insufficient`,
  toSort.complex
  .sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b))
  .join(`\n`)
);

// so, [Choice > 9] needs more work

// The plan:
// 1. Sort on string start (e.g. '1.2', 'C'), create 
// an Object from that with key = string start, 
// values = [next values] and convert it to an 
// Array of entries;
// 2. Sort numeric within the entries Array on the 
// last value ('Choice [value]'), which is already 
// converted to number. Remap the result to sorted 
// strings.
const linesSorted = Object.entries(toSort.complex /*1*/
    .map(v => v.split(/[\s-]/))
    .sort(([a, , ], [b, , ]) => a.localeCompare(b))
    .reduce( (acc, [v1, v2, v3]) =>
      ({ ...acc, [v1]: [...(acc[v1] || []), [v2, +v3]]}), {} ) )
  .reduce( (acc, [key, value]) => /*2*/
    [...acc, [key, 
      value.sort(([, a], [, b]) => a - b, [] ).map(v => 
        `${key} ${v.join(` `)}`)]], [])
  .map(([, value]) => value.join(`\n`))
  .join(`\n`);

log(`\n**Choice may be [> 9], need more work`, linesSorted);

// helpers
function getToSort() {
  // return strings to sort, already splitted to array
  return {
    simple: `5.3 Choice 3
      A-Choice 4
      1.2 Choice 1
      1.5 Choice 2
      C-Choice 5`.split(`\n`).map(v => v.trim()),
    complex: `1.5 Choice 3
      5.3 Choice 3
      1.2 Choice 55
      A-Choice 4
      1.2 Choice 1
      1.5 Choice 11
      C-Choice 5
      A-Choice 110
      1.2 Choice 2`.split(`\n`).map(v => v.trim())
  };
}

function log(...strs) {
  const pre = document.querySelector(`pre`);
  strs.forEach(str => pre.textContent += `${str}\n`);
}
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be achieved with [localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare).

```js
const arr = [
  '5.3 Choice 3',
  'A-Choice 4',
  '1.2 Choice 1',
  '1.5 Choice 2',
  'C-Choice 5',
];

const result = arr.sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: thanks but it's not working if I have for exemple 10.5 Choice 15
It will be display before 5.3 Choice 3